# SQL Select Case (2 forms, 3 values)

Tags: sql, select, multiple-tables

Can the following be done, and can someone tell me some pseudo-code for my Select statement.

Form 1 contains date field RevDate
Form 2 contains date fields RevDate, CompletedDate

Form 1 can be linked to Form 2
Form 1 may not have a link to Form 2

If Form 1 has no link want to select Form1_RevDate
If Form 1 has a link, want to select

- Form2_RevDate if Form2_CompletedDate is null or
- Form2_CompletedDate if Form2_CompletedDate is not null

Comment: you're going to want to `LEFT JOIN` your two tables together, such that the `RevDate` columns are linked, but you get `NULL` values if no such matching rows exist in the second table.  Then you want to use `nvl()` (or `ISNULL`, depending on your database system) to choose which field to select in the event your desired field is null.  Give it a shot, and update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: What values are in the table? is there a primary key? give an example of the result you expect

Comment: Thanks @Paul LJoined my two tables and was able to use this in my select statement:  CASE WHEN SEC_APPROVALS.REV_DATE IS NULL THEN (COALESCE (SEC_APPROVALS.REVISION_DATE_1, QMS_DOCUMENTS_1.REVISION_DATE_2)) ELSE (SEC_APPROVALS.REV_DATE) END QM_DOCUMENT_1_TRU_REVISIO_DATE